# My mock function is not called more than once

Tags: javascript

I have a problem.
I'm setting up an anonymous function

```
let getLisMock = sinon.mock();
GetListMock.calledWith({data: 'data'});
```

The function I'm testing

```
function someFunc({data: 'data'}, callback) {  
 async.retry({times: 3,interval: 10}, function(callback){  
 getList({data: 'data'}, callback);  },
 callback) 
}
```

I combine someFunc and getList with rewire and `__set__`
The settings of sinon before the function is called look like this

```
GetListMock.onCall(0).yields(new Error('error'), null);
GetListMock.onCall(1).yields(null, {items: [{id: 1}]});
```

Next, call the function and expect.

Whatever I do I get an error: Uncaught ExpectationError: Anonymous mock already called once

P.S Sorry for the question in this format, I don't have access to a computer right now. A little later, if no one answers, I will add a test sample.

I tried making one call with once() and just throwing an error, but in the end all roads led me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `GetListMock.twice()` first:

```
GetListMock.twice();
GetListMock.onCall(0).yields(new Error('error'), null);
GetListMock.onCall(1).yields(null, {items: [{id: 1}]});
```